# Single Sign-On from Google to Salesforce

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps, federated-authentication

Considering one of my client is using Google Apps and Salesforce, I think it would be a lot simpler for the users to login to Salesforce using Gmail interface, with Single Sign-On / OAuth.

I read on Salesforce Website that it is possible to do that from Salesforce -> Google (federated authentification). Is there an existing solution to do the same, but from the Google interface?

---

Example:

- A user has access to 1 Salesforce account: using an app available in the header in Gmail, he can click on the link and automaticaly login to his Salesforce account;
- A user has access to multiple Salesforce accounts (production, sandbox...): using the same app, he could click on any organization and authentificated automaticaly.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can SSO into one or more target Salesforce orgs via OpenID Connect from Google: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&language=en_US

UPDATE (Nov 2016): Google Apps now supports SAML (since Mar 2016) for outbound SSO.

Comment: FreeSSO from Groove Labs ( https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5COhEAN ) simplifies the complete process. [ I'm not affiliated with Groove Labs ]